# Query string substitutions for links on a page

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, url

If the current page URL has an argument 'myid1' or 'myid2' in the querystring, for each link in my webpage with class 'rewrite', I want the link href's querystring to be replaced by the current page URL's querystring. I'm using the code given below. Since I'm new to javascript, I'm not sure if its optimized. I want it to execute as fast as possible.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var requestid = gup('myid1');
    if (requestid) {
        $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
            var base = this.href;
            var pos = base.indexOf("?");
            if (pos != -1) {
                base = base.substr(0, pos);
            }
            this.href = base + "?myid1=" + requestid;
        })
    }
    var requestid2 = gup('myid2');
    if (requestid2) {
        $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
            var base = this.href;
            var pos = base.indexOf("?");
            if (pos != -1) {
                base = base.substr(0, pos);
            }
            this.href = base + "?myid2=" + requestid2;
        })
    }
})

function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.website.com/?someid=1234" class="rewrite">Hyperlink</a>
```

Comment: Optimization is easy, don't use jQuery.

Comment: @Raynos How do you suppose I do that? It doesn't work without jquery.

Comment: Use this thing called the DOM. Maybe QSA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not very much you can do about the performance.

You can remove the repeated code using a loop:

```
$(function() {
  $.each(['myid1', 'myid2'], function(index, id){
    var requestid = gup(id);
    if (requestid != "") {
      $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
        var base = this.href;
        var pos = base.indexOf("?");
        this.href = (pos != -1 ? base.substr(0, pos) : base) + "?" + id + "=" + requestid;
      });
    }
  });
})
```

In the `gup` function you can use a single replace instead of two:

```
function gup(name) {
  var pattern = "[\\?&]" + name.replace(/([\[\]])/g,"\\$1") + "=([^&#]*)";
  var results = new RegExp(pattern).exec(window.location.href);
  return results == null ? "" : results[1];
}
```

(Try to use more descriptive names than "gup", though...)

Comment: `var results = new RegExp(pattern).exec(window.location.href);` still execute each time a link `href` is altered. Not efficient, see my post.

Comment: @yangchenyun: You are mistaken. Look at the code again. The call to the `gup` function where that code is, is *outside* the loop that changes the links.

Comment: Yep, it is optimized than original code, but the **same calculation** to fetch key/value pair from `window.location.href` still repeat itself for each id (myid1, myid2) which could be optimized.  My method use an regular expression to fetch **all** the key-value pair **at once** and cache the result for later usage.

Comment: @yangchenyun: Yes *that* is true, but on the other hand you are looping through **all** query string values, even if they are not going to be used.

Answer (score 2):

### The code you provide is inefficient in two ways:

1. **Unnecessary loops**. It loops through `a.rewrite` anchor each time for one querystring match. It could be optimized into one loop;
2. **Repeated calculation** on regular expression matches. `regexS` is executed for each `gup` function and it could be reduced into one calculation.

### The solutions are:

1. Fetch the `window.location.href` data into one variable which could be referred to later;
2. Integrate the two (or more) loops into one and finish all the replacement in one loop.

### Here the optimized code goes:

```
//First you fetch the query string as key-value pairs in the window.location.href, this equals your gup function.

//This code, fetch the ?key1=value1&key2=value2 pair into an javaScript Object {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
var queryString = {}; 
var queryStringPattern = new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g");
window.location.href.replace(
    queryStringPattern,
    function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
);

//Second you collect all the anchor with class rewrite and execute the replacement.

$("a.rewrite").each(function () {
  this.href.replace(
    queryStringPattern,
    function ($0, $1, $2, $3) {
      return queryString[$1] ? $1 +  "=" + queryString[$1] : $1 + '=' + $3;
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. Where exactly should I insert "myid1" & "myid2"? There is going to be only one key at a time in the url. So, I won't require fetching multiple values like `?key1=value1&key2=value2` etc.

Comment: It's certainly more readable, so props for that. Did you try an actual benchmark for empirical proof? In particular, I'm curious how $.each would stack up against `$.attr("href", function … )`

Comment: @Shyam Sundar This code behaves the same with your former code and it **doesn't care which variable name you use in your query string** If in the window url you have `?key1=value1&key2=value2`, it will substitute all the anchor elements whose `href` contains either `key1=anothervalue` or `key2=anothervalue`  to `key1=value` and `key2=value`. The replacement happens on the line `return queryString[$1] ? $1 +  "=" + queryString[$1] : $1 + '=' + $3;`

Comment: @kojiro Didn't know tools to run benchmarks. Also interested in `$.attr("href", function … )` performance against `$.each` and `this.href`.

Comment: @yangchenyun consider http://jsperf.com/ for simple pseudo-benchmarks. When more precision is needed, you'll have to devise a controlled local environment, but for this I think jsperf will do fine.